# $G$ is the semidirect product of $U_n$ & $D_n$

Tags: group-theory

Let $GL_n \Bbb R$ be the set of all invertible matrices of size n. Let  $U_n$ be the set of upper triangular matrices with $1$'s on the diagonal and $D_n$ be the set of diagonal matrices with non-zero entries. Let G be the subgroup generated by $U_n$ & $D_n$. Prove that  $G $ is the semidirect product of $U_n$ & $D_n$.

It is clear that $U_n$ is normal in $G$. But what is the order of Aut($U_n$)?
 and What will be the map? Please help.

Comment: $U_n$ _isn't_ a normal subgroup. Geometrically, it's the group that stabilises a complete flag of subspaces, conjugation of such an element stabilises a different flag. And dimensionwise the semidirect product can't fill up all of $GL_n$... Also, why tag this question "finite groups"?

Comment: @  Olivier Bégassat, I have edited it. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @user152715, you haven't edited the biggest mistake: $\;U_n\;$ is *not* normal in $\;G\;$ ...and  nor is $\;D_n\;$ , so how are you going to form a semidirect product with them?.

Comment: @Timbuc Can you tell me why $U_n$ is not normal in G?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat, are you sure that $U_n$ is not normal in the subgroup of $GL_n$ generated by $U_n$ and $D_n$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez My comment was about the original formulation of the question, where all $GL_n(\Bbb R)$ was supposed to be the semidirect product of $U_n$ and $D_n$.

Comment: It will probably be best if we remove the comments relevant only to the old version.

Comment: I also referred to the original question: neither $\;U_n\;$ nor $\;D_n\;$ are normal in the general linear group.

Comment: Its ok. It was my mistake. Now I have edited it.